# Node.js upgrade still shows older version in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, version, upgrade, reinstall

I have downloaded and installed the new version of nodejs (4.1.2) using the .msi installer. After that I ran `node -v`, but it still shows the older version (0.12.2). I tried restarting Windows and even uninstalled nodejs and reinstalled it, but still it shows the same. Why is that happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You might want to check your path variable and make sure it is not pointing to an older version of node.js

Comment: Path variables are ok. I installed on the same directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run a search for multiple copies of node.exe in the usual install paths:

- Program Files

  ```
    Get-ChildItem -File -path $env:PROGRAMFILES -include node.exe -recurse -force
  ```
- Program Files(x86)

  ```
    Get-ChildItem -File -path $env:PROGRAMFILESX86 -include node.exe -recurse -force
  ```
- Common Files

  ```
    Get-ChildItem -File -path $env:COMMONPROGRAMFILES -include node.exe -recurse -force
  ```
- Roaming

  ```
    Get-ChildItem -File -path $env:APPDATA -include node.exe -recurse -force
  ```

Upgrading npm has its own issues:

> Chances are that you attempted to upgrade npm before, it somehow failed, and you then went looking for this tool. If the tool fails to upgrade, it may be troubled by partial changes done during `npm install npm` or `npm upgrade npm`. In that case, you will have to completely uninstall Node:
>
> Uninstall Node.js (select Uninstall, not the Repair option).
>
> Go into `%programfiles%\nodejs` and delete the entire folder.
>
> Delete `%appdata%\npm` and `%appdata%\npm-cache`.
>
> Edit your PATH and remove everything that references npm (to do so, hit "Start" and search for "Environment Variables").
>
> Reinstall Node, then install [this tool](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade) - and only use [this tool](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade) to upgrade npm, do not attempt to run `npm install npm`.

**References**

- [npmjs docs: Prefix Configuration](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#prefix-Configuration)
- [Get-ChildItem for FileSystem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847897.aspx)
- [Finding files in the PATH with PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2015/07/02/finding-files-in-the-path-with-powershell/)
- [Microsoft NodeJS Guidelines](https://github.com/microsoft/nodejs-guidelines)
- [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration (System)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Common folder variables - Windows Defender Security Intelligence](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/help/folder-variables)
- [KNOWNFOLDERID (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Well, I solved this problem long ago. The reason of this problem was indeed multiple existence of node.js installation.

Comment: I had a similar issue, had two instances of node installed, so I removed one through Control Panel, other one, older version, I just deleted the folder. After this clean installation of new version works with no issues. Thx Paul.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and resolved it by deleting the node.js folder in program files (x64) and it w

Answer (score 0):

I had remove Nsolid path from Environment. it should be relate to node.exe in different path, make sure Nsolid, %appdata%/npm dont have node.exe file.