# How to update Powershell node js and npm version

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I have got different versions of node.js within `PowerShell` and `Node.js command prompt` as seen below.

I setup the latest version of Nodejs by installing the MSI.

How do I update or change PowerShell node and npm version? I want the same versions in PowerShell and CMD.

[image: Screenshots my powershell and nodejs command prompt]

Comment: Did you check the contents of your PATH and uninstall older versions?

Comment: I never installed old version of nodejs. How I check PATH? What should be? @Seth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js upgrade still shows older version in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014865/node-js-upgrade-still-shows-older-version-in-windows)

Comment: When I installed nodejs x86 version, they were same version.